# Inserindo objetos em um array através de um loop

Tags: javascript, array

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo solucionar no momento. Estou tentando e não consigo chegar numa solução.

Basicamente quero inserir vários objetos dentro de um array. Estou fazendo o seguinte, imagino que esteja errado o que estou tentando fazer, qual seria a forma correta de se inserir objetos no array? Creio que também estou errando no método push:

```
const aniversario = []

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      aniversario.push(i) = {
      nome: 'Thiago',
      idade: 20
      diaDoAniversario: '7/12/2020'
    }
    console.log('Aniversarios sendo inseridos', aniversario[i])
  }
  console.log('aniversario 8', aniversario[8])
  console.log('Total de itens', aniversario.length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você tem que entender melhor o que é uma [**função** em JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es).

Vamos verificar esta parte do código:

> ```js
> aniversario.push(i) = {
>   nome: 'Thiago',
>   idade: 20
>   diaDoAniversario: '7/12/2020'
> }
> ```

Note que você está chamando o método [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (`push`), passando o valor da variável `i`. Isso irá inserir (ao final do array) o valor de `i` a cada iteração, até terminar o laço.

Mas note que, ao retorno do método `push` (que no caso é o novo comprimento do array) você está tentando atribuir o objeto literal (note o operador de atribuição `=` que, naquele caso, não está fazendo nada de útil). É a mesma coisa que tentar atribuir um objeto a um número, assim:

```
// Este código não faz sentido e lançará um erro de sintaxe.
1 = { name: 'Foo' };
```

Isso não faz sentido, já que você quer inserir o objeto no array. Portanto, você deve chamar o `push` passando, como argumento, o próprio valor que quer inserir. Nesse caso, é o próprio objeto literal.

Terá, então, algo assim:

```js
const aniversario = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  aniversario.push({
      nome: 'Thiago',
      idade: 20,
      diaDoAniversario: '7/12/2020'
  });
}
console.log('aniversario 8', aniversario[8])
console.log('Total de itens', aniversario.length)
```

Você pode até utilizar a atribuição para inserir algum valor em um *array*, mas não é muito necessário, já que o `push` faz isso de graça para você. De todo modo, para atribuir, precisará utilizar a notação de colchetes:

```js
let arr = [];
arr[0] = 'A';
arr[1] = 'B';
arr[2] = 'C';

console.log(arr); //=> ['A', 'B', 'C']
console.log(arr.length); //=> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A maneira correta utilizando o método `push` é passar o objeto novo criado integramente, exemplo:

```
const aniversarios = []
aniversarios.push({ ... objeto criado});
```

Exemplo final:

```js
const aniversarios = []

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  const aniversario = {
    nome: 'Thiago',
    idade: 20,
    diaDoAniversario: '7/12/2020'
  };
  aniversarios.push(aniversario);
}
console.log(aniversarios); 
console.log('aniversario 8', aniversarios[8])
console.log('Total de itens', aniversarios.length)
```